# Customize pageview Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a pageView in flutter that shows the preview of the current and next page and hides the preview of the previous page as is in the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76eht.png). How can I achieve that?

I have tried viewportFraction but it also shows the previous page

Comment: You can use `Stack` and `Positionned`to hide a factinnal size

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. You should show your attempt at the code and what issues you are facing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask